# Gaps between the shades

Tags: brick

Hey my home has this shades under the windows on the brick wall. The filling between the shade is loosening or falling off.
How do I fix it? Do I have to call a contractor or can I do it?

[image]      [image]

Comment: How about a few pictures so we can see what you see.

Comment: That would usually be called a "ledge" or possibly a "sill", not a shade - they're far too shallow to provide much shade. As to whether _you_ can do it or not is entirely up to you. Are you generally mechanically inclined and feel comfortable learning a new skill (and, it appears, working on a ladder)? If so, you can probably learn how to do it, if no to any of those questions, then you may be better off hiring a pro. A better question to ask would be "How do I fix the mortar that's falling out from between these concrete pieces".

Comment: So I can do it by filling mortar between ? I was going to try it myself first and see if it fixed the problem

Comment: That doesn't look like the kind of gap for which mortar would work well. It looks very shallow and any mortar you put in there would probably fall out within a few weeks (if it even lasts that long). I'd look for a similar-colored silicone or polyurethane-based caulk instead.

Comment: Is the stuff that is currently in the gap hard and rough like concrete/mortar or is it soft and spongy like caulk? If the caulk is old enough to be drying and breaking out, it may be pretty hard but not as hard as concrete (you could make a dent in it with a nail or other hard object), and it will be reasonably smooth with a surface texture very different than the concrete and mortar near it.

Comment: The current one definitely mortar. Very hard to touch , and has the same colour as mortar in the brick exterior. 
So should I go with mortar or caulk?